# Solutions for $n$? Use Stirling approximations if needed

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving, factorial, analytic-number-theory

$$(2n)! =  a^{2n}$$
where $a \in \mathbb R$, and $n \in \mathbb N$.

This is relevant because of a research question I'd asked and [received an answer to by Sotiris here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321583/what-partial-sum-formulae-exist-for-this-basic-hypergeometric-series/321777#321777)

Answer (score 0):

If we use Stirling as you suggest we have 
$$(2n)!=a^{2n}\\\frac {(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}\sqrt {4\pi n}=a^{2n}\\
(4\pi n)^{1/(4n)}=\frac {ae}{2n}$$
Let us define $x=\frac 1n$.  This becomes
$$(\frac {4\pi}x)^{(x/4)}=\frac 12aex\\
x=\frac 2{ae}(\frac {4\pi}x)^{(x/4)}$$
Some might find a way to use the Lambert W function, but I see this as a fixed point iteration.  Choose a starting value $x_0$, plug it into the right, compute $x_1$, plug that in, and iterate to convergence.  I just started with $x_0=0.1$ and it converged quickly for $a=3,10,50,1000,1000000$  Starting with $x_0=\frac 1a$ may be even better.